# How can javascript parse a Rails generated query string with nested values into JSON?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, url, prototype

Rails allows the generation of query strings by passing a hash to a url_for type helper:

```
root_path({ :animals => {:dogs => ['pluto','spot'], :cats => 'garfield'} })
```

This will generate a url like:

```
http://example.com/?animals[dogs][]=pluto&animals[dogs][]=spot&animals[cats]=garfield
```

I want to use javascript to turn this into a JSON object so I have an object that matches the hash passed into the url helper in rails.

Using prototype.js I can call:

```
var params = window.location.search.toQueryParams();
```

params is a object but the original nested structure is not retained, instead I get:

```
{
  "animals[dogs][]" : ["pluto","spot"],
  "animals[cats]" : "garfield"
}
```

What I really want is:

```
{
  "animals" : {
    "dogs" : ["pluto","spot"],
    "cats" : "garfield"
  }
}
```

Also the reverse would be useful too. Prototype.js has toQueryString which in this case just returns an empty string:

```
Object.toQueryString({
  "animals" : {
    "dogs" : ["pluto","spot"],
    "cats" : "garfield"
  }
});
```

Is there a library of method that provides for this?

Comment: I really need a prototype.js solution to work with my current app.

Comment: Found this discussion and apparent decision to not support my requirement in the official prototype.js  http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-core/browse_thread/thread/140fdf88eed057d/7d610ec81f74b313

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

I found Ben Alman's jQuery BBQ which does it with a jQuery plugin.

[http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/?animals[dogs][]=pluto&animals[dogs][]=spot&animals[cats]=garfield](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/?animals%5bdogs%5d%5b%5d=pluto&animals%5bdogs%5d%5b%5d=spot&animals%5bcats%5d=garfield)